# How to know if user accepts the currency?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm integrating paypal into a marketplace, and I just had a payment failing with the following error:

error id: 559044
message: The receiver .... does not accept payments in this Currency

I was able to fix this by logging into the account and adding the currency (EUR) to balance currencies for the account.

now... I need to be able to detect when 'sellers' in the marketplace do not have EUR enabled, so that I can guide them through the process and verify they completed it. Otherwise its a bad experience for buyers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PP_MTS_Chad is right, there is no API for that. But you can very well use AdaptivePayments' PAY call with a dummy amount to find out whether it throws a 559044 error message. If it does the receiver does not accept the given currency, as you already found out by yourself ;)
This is certainly not the nicest solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API or anything you can do to tell what they they have set up in their profile as far as currencies aside from logging into the account and going to the profile and checking the settings.